# Why doesn't my variable interpolate correctly when I build up a Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to write a regex expresstion in mysql from a Perl program. I want to have query such as this:

```
WHERE a.keywords REGEXP '[[:<:]]something[[:>:]]'
```

However, in Perl when I make this query I am getting error when concatenating:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $where = $where . "'[[:<:]]$andkeywords[$i][[:>:]]' ";  #errors
```

Where as this does not give me an error:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $where = $where . "'[[:<:]] $andkeywords[$i] [[:>:]]' ";  #no error
```

In the 'no error' code notice that there are extra spaces.  But if I have extra spaces then I do not get the resuls I want because in the DB there are no 'extra spaces'.

Comment: It's always helpful to include the errors in your message. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never really trusted the autoreplacment of variables in strings like that. You may want to consider explicitly doing the concatenation you want like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $where=$where . "'[[:<:]]" . $andkeywords[$i] . "[[:>:]]' ";
```

**EDIT:**
As [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) points out the generally accepted way to do this inline is

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $where=$where . "'[[:<:]]${andkeywords[$i]}[[:>:]]' ";
```

Personally I find the first way more readable but as with all things Perl, [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Comment: I'm getting cognitive dissonance from seeing "officially correct way" and "TMTOWTDI" in the same post ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness sake, this works too:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $where .= "'[[:<:]]${andkeywords[$i]}[[:>:]]' ";
}
```

`${blah}` isn't valid outside of a string, but inside of a interpolatable string, it's equivalent to `$blah`.

I would have thought that this pattern is more common than the other answers, though... after all, how else do you want to type `"foo${var}bar"`?  Obviously `"foo$var\bar"` doesn't work, since `\b` is a recognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 6):

The reason in this case is that "$andkeywords[$i][[:>:]]" is being interpreted as a multi-dimensional array, and :>: is not a valid array index.

I personally prefer Mykroft's approach, but you could also achieve the same result by escaping the final opening bracket as so:

```
$where=$where."'[[:<:]]$andkeywords[$i]\[[:>:]]' ";
```

Answer (score 6):

`<Obligatory security moan>`

**Please** use a `DBI` parameter for each regex value instead of interpolating it.  Why?

1. There are no longer any constraints on what characters are allowed.  Currently, if any element of `@andkeywords` contains a quote, backslash or special regex character, things will break.  E.g. the keyword `"O'Reilly"` will cause a database error.
2. People won't be able to construct malicious keywords to reveal information they shouldn't see or wreak havoc.  (Imagine if a user entered `"'; drop database;"` as a keyword.) This is called an SQL injection attack, and the web is *rife* with poorly coded websites that are susceptible to them.  Don't let yours be one of them.

Even if `@andkeywords` is not populated from user-entered data, it takes almost no extra effort to use DBI parameters, and your code will be safe for use in future unknown environments.

`</Obligatory security moan>`

Comment: Thank you, jrh, for going beyond answering "how do I interpolate this string" to add "but you really shouldn't be interpolating a string there in the first place".

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would include the text of any error messages.

Something tells me that

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $where=$where . "'[[:<:]]" . $andkeywords[$i] . "[[:>:]]' ";
    ...
}
```

Could be simplified to

```
for (@andkeywords) {
    $where .= qq('[[:<:]]${_}[[:>]]' );
    ...
}
```

Or perhaps

```
$where .= join ' ', map { qq('[[:<:]]${_}[[:>:]]') } @andkeywords;
```